# pushViewController not working

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am new to ios with **swift** and **swrevealviewcontroller**. i faceing a problem! in my slide menu (scene TableViewController  Two blue line draw) each row when selected then should be open particuler `scene` (View controller) but unfortunatly it is not open . there have no error and `didselectRowAt` fire when i select row from the table but pushViewController not working .

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let dvcStoryBordId = menuViewIds[(indexPath.row - 1 )]

        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: dvcStoryBordId )

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
```

Story Board

[image]

do i miss anything ? is it correct way ? self.

UPDATE :

`self.navigationController` is `nil` . is there any alternative ?  or without navigation

**Update:**

Storyboard Id

```
menuViewIds = ["shareWithFriends","deliveryTracking", "controls", "support","myAccount"]
```

Run time view

[image]

Comment: Please debug and check self.navigationController is not null.

Comment: @user4887505 self.navigationController is nil . what should i do

Comment: Make your "menu Controller" with "navigation Controller".

Comment: @user4887505 how can i do that ?

Comment: from the image of your storyboard it seems that your Slide TableViewController (the one with the blue lines) is not wrapped in a navigation controller, so therefore the navigationController is `nil`. So either you could wrap/embed it in a navigationController or you could just use `present` on the Slide TableViewController.

Comment: @pbodsk thanks your valuable information

Comment: you're welcome. Got it working?

Comment: @pbodsk not yet just a good idea

Comment: Note that `IndexPath` is zero-based, so double check if `menuViewIds[(indexPath.row - 1 )]` is really what you meant.

Comment: @zisoft thanks but my first row is profile image and name load form xib file  and check my update section guide me this scenario

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         let dvcStoryBordId = menuViewIds[(indexPath.row - 1 )]
         let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: dvcStoryBordId )
         var navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

   }
```

Comment: it is working but back button not showing .. what should i do ?

Comment: please check now.

Comment: sorry please check now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128694/discussion-between-cristan-lika-and-user4887505).

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'LifeFast.ViewController' (0x10e127910) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1109adf18).

Comment: according to image, i think  first row last image your menu Controller if yes then  can you access viewController object in your method “didSelectRowAt indexPath” ?

Comment: no! second row 1st image . please check my update section

Comment: can you access this viewController object in your method “didSelectRowAt indexPath” ?

Comment: which one you taking about 
?

Comment: I am taking about “viewController” in which your menu come first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         let dvcStoryBordId = menuViewIds[indexPath.row]
         let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: dvcStoryBordId )
         let vc = windowRootViewController() as! SWRevealViewController
         let nvc = vc.frontViewController as! UINavigationController
         nvc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
   }
```

WindowRootVC() :

```
func windowRootViewController() -> UIViewController {
    return (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController)!
}
```